# What would the OS see if the JVM was memory starved?

Tags: jvm

The real context here is elasticsearch but I'm curious what would happen more generally (minecraft / jetty / etc).  When an OS process is out of system memory, you can see this behavior by checking swap.  If a box isn't swapping then it doesn't need more memory (I believe this is mostly always true).

What would the OS see if the JVM is starved with too low of a `-Xmx` value?  Would the JVM spend time managing internal pages?  Would this come across as CPU wait / load?  Or is the only way to be sure is by using java-aware tooling to reach into the JVM and observe more precisely?

Answer (score 4):

Since Java is a JVM, it takes care of memory operations internally. The OS gives java a -Xmx block of  memory and that is it.  A tool like jstat can look inside the JVM and tell you how much time is being spent on GC overhead, as can java agents like NewRelic.

You can also set -verbose:gc to get the JVM to log GC behavior.

If you lack any of these tools, low memory in a java process will often appear as a process that is using lots of CPU -- the JVM is continually garbage collecting which is CPU heavy.